# Problem with overlaying polygons onto DEM with qgis2threejs plugin

Tags: qgis, javascript, qgis-plugins, dem, qgis2threejs

I am trying to export a scene using qgis2threejs, adding a polygon layer overlay on top of a DEM and a satellite image. After exporting, it looks like the polygons don't overlay onto the DEM correctly. I get gaps like in the photo below. I have tried messing with the Z coordinates of the layer (I have it set so it's relative to the DEM). The vertical exaggeration of the DEM has no effect. Does anyone know a solution to this?

[image: This is how the polygon layer appears after exporting.]

Comment: Which z coordinates did you mess with?  If possible, please show a screenshot of your tool settings.